# Laravel 4 Post and categories

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent, article

I'm new in laravel. I need to have in my homepageBlog fetch 3 posts for each categories and just show 4 categories.

I'm doing in my HomeController

```
  $categories = Category::with(['posts' => function($query){
      $query->orderBy('published_at', 'DESC')->take(3)->get();
  }])->take(4)->get();
```

In my model

```
//post models
     public function category(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Category', 'post_categories', 'post_id', 'category_id');
    }
```

in my category model

```
    public function posts(){
       return $this->hasMany('Post');
   }
```

But when I'm going in my view it's just showing 3 latest post only for 1 category and show 1 post for another.

Comment: Are you used a 'post_categories' pivot table for many to many relationship between 'category' and 'post' table ?

Comment: no pivot table with category and post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for your controller:

```
// declare a variable and an array
$catid = null;
$posts = [];

// get four categories
$categories = Category::take(4)->get();

foreach($categories as $category){
  //foreach of the four categories, get the category id
  $catid = $category->category_id;

  //add three posts of each of those categories to the $posts array
  $posts[] = Category::where('category_id', $catid)->take(3)->get();

}
```

Your `$posts` array should have everything you need.

Comment: i have no pivot table only in post a foreign key category_id so when i do myforeach($categories as $category){
  //foreach of the four categories, get the category id
  $category_id = $category->$category_id;

  //add three posts of each of those categories to the $posts array
  $posts[] = Category::where('category_id', $category_id)->take(3)->get();

}i have a error message Undefined variable: category_id

Comment: And for Category::find(4) return only my Category id number 5 not return 4 categories

Comment: Undefined variable: category_id i don't understand why i have this problem

Comment: do you still have this problem?

Comment: yes i have the problem of category_id undefined i don't know why

Comment: did you declare the variable as mentioned? $category_id; ?

Comment: yes i have decared $categoryid like in the upper answer

Comment: try declaring it in the for loop;
foreach($categories as $category){
$category_id;
}

Comment: Ok i try it And coming after to say if it's ok

Comment: true, adding the declaring the variable inside the for loop will not work but i think it should be working when you declare the $category_id as a global variable. i made some changes in the code. check if it works